# Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file

Tags: java, android, ffmpeg

I am trying to add text in the video, but I am getting -

> **Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
>       [Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0xea1aeaa0] impossible to init fontconfig**

below cmd to add text using FFmpeg lib-

> **String[] cmd = new String[] {
>                    "-i", savedVideoFilePath, "-vf", "drawtext=text="+"'"+timeStamp+"'"+":
>   fontfile=/android_asset/fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf: fontcolor=white:
>   fontsize=24: x=(w-tw)/2: y=(h/PHI)+th box=0:","-codec:a" ,"copy" ,
>   output_path };**

log details -

> Error opening filters! 2019-06-10 18:04:58.027
>   18678-18678/com.rs.vir.debug E/FFMPEG FAilure: FAILED with output :
>   ffmpeg version n3.0.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2016 the FFmpeg developers
>         built with gcc 4.8 (GCC)
>         configuration: --target-os=linux --cross-prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/bin/arm-linux-androideabi-
>   --arch=arm --cpu=cortex-a8 --enable-runtime-cpudetect --sysroot=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/sysroot
>   --enable-pic --enable-libx264 --enable-libass --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libmp3lame --enable-fontconfig --enable-pthreads --disable-debug --disable-ffserver --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --disable-ffplay --disable-ffprobe --enable-gpl --enable-yasm --disable-doc --disable-shared --enable-static --pkg-config=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/ffmpeg-pkg-config --prefix=/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/build/armeabi-v7a --extra-cflags='-I/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/include
>   -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fno-strict-overflow -fstack-protector-all' --extra-ldflags='-L/home/vagrant/SourceCode/ffmpeg-android/toolchain-android/lib
>   -Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now -pie' --extra-libs='-lpng -lexpat -lm' --extra-cxxflags=
>         libavutil      55. 17.103 / 55. 17.103
>         libavcodec     57. 24.102 / 57. 24.102
>         libavformat    57. 25.100 / 57. 25.100
>         libavdevice    57.  0.101 / 57.  0.101
>         libavfilter     6. 31.100 /  6. 31.100
>         libswscale      4.  0.100 /  4.  0.100
>         libswresample   2.  0.101 /  2.  0.101
>         libpostproc    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
>       Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '/data/user/0/com.rs.vir.debug/files/VIR_Customer/EVINV12207201906100303240000/Videos/sample.mp4':
>         Metadata:
>           major_brand     : mp42
>           minor_version   : 0
>           compatible_brands: isommp42
>           creation_time   : 2019-06-10 12:34:55
>           com.android.version: 8.1.0
>         Duration: 00:00:06.66, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 3724 kb/s
>           Stream #0:0(eng): Video: h264 (High) (avc1 / 0x31637661), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/smpte170m/bt709), 720x480, 3464 kb/s, SAR 1:1
>   DAR 3:2, 30.04 fps, 30 tbr, 90k tbn, 180k tbc (default)
>           Metadata:
>             rotate          : 90
>             creation_time   : 2019-06-10 12:34:55
>             handler_name    : VideoHandle
>           Side data:
>             displaymatrix: rotation of -90.00 degrees
>           Stream #0:1(eng): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp, 255 kb/s (default)
>           Metadata:
>             creation_time   : 2019-06-10 12:34:55
>             handler_name    : SoundHandle
>       Fontconfig error: Cannot load default config file
>       [Parsed_drawtext_0 @ 0xea1aeaa0] impossible to init fontconfig
>       [AVFilterGraph @ 0xea1cb040] Error initializing filter 'drawtext' with args
>   'text=java.util.GregorianCalendar[time=1560170097814,areFieldsSet=true,areAllFieldsSet=true,lenient=true,zone=libcore.util.ZoneInfo[id="Asia/Kolkata",mRawOffset=19800000,mEarliestRawOffset=19800000,mUseDst=false,mDstSavings=0,transitions=5],firstDayOfWeek=2,minimalDaysInFirstWeek=4,ERA=1,YEAR=2019,MONTH=5,WEEK_OF_YEAR=24,WEEK_OF_MONTH=2,DAY_OF_MONTH=10,DAY_OF_YEAR=161,DAY_OF_WEEK=2,DAY_OF_WEEK_IN_MONTH=2,AM_PM=1,HOUR=6,HOUR_OF_DAY=18,MINUTE=4,SECOND=57,MILLISECOND=814,ZONE_OFFSET=19800000,DST_OFFSET=0]:
>   fontfile=/android_asset/fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf: fontcolor=white:
>   fontsize=24: x=(w-tw)/2: y=(h/PHI)+th box=0:'
>       Error opening filters!

please give me the solution for this.

Comment: /android_asset/fonts/Poppins-Medium.ttf file path can not be used by ffmpeg. provide external file path

Comment: external path means I need to put same ttf file in different folder..?

Comment: store ttf file from asset fdirectory to device storage and access

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem with fonts which I was using, changed code as below-

```
   mFileFont = new File("/system/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf");
        if (!mFileFont.exists())
            mFileFont = new File("/system/fonts/DroidSerif-Regular.ttf");
   String[] cmd = new String[]{
                "-i", savedVideoFilePath, "-vf", "drawtext=text=" + "'" + todaysdate
                + "'" + ": fontfile=" + mFileFont.getAbsolutePath() + ": 
               fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: x=20: y=50: box=0:", "-codec:a", "copy", 
              "-preset", "ultrafast", "-b:a", "128k", output_path};
```

Comment: can we write multiple text  in any direction. like  text abc at right position top and efg at left position top.. is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Copy File from assets Directory to Internal Storage using below method.

```
private void copyAssets() {
    AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();
    String[] files = null;
try {
    files = assetManager.list("");
} catch (IOException e) {
    Log.e("tag", "Failed to get asset file list.", e);
  }
 for(String filename : files) {
    InputStream in = null;
    OutputStream out = null;
    try {
      in = assetManager.open(filename);

      String outDir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/X/Y/Z/" ; 

      File outFile = new File(outDir, filename);

      out = new FileOutputStream(outFile);
      copyFile(in, out);
      in.close();
      in = null;
      out.flush();
      out.close();
        out = null;
      } catch(IOException e) {
          Log.e("tag", "Failed to copy asset file: " + filename, e);
         }       
       }
     }
     private void copyFile(InputStream in, OutputStream out) throws IOException {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
      int read;
     while((read = in.read(buffer)) != -1){
       out.write(buffer, 0, read);
     }
   }
```

then pass your ttf file path to ffmpeg command

```
String[] cmd = new String[] { "-i", savedVideoFilePath, "-vf", "drawtext=text="+"'"+timeStamp+"'"+": fontfile=<YOUR_DIRECTORY_PATH>/Poppins-Medium.ttf: fontcolor=white: fontsize=24: x=(w-tw)/2: y=(h/PHI)+th box=0:","-codec:a" ,"copy" , output_path };
```

we only can use `"file:///android_assets"` for android purpose. but we cant use it for native projects